# How to prevent text/event-stream streams from being buffered by eager web proxies?

Tags: web-server, proxy, http

I am writing an application which uses [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to push updates to the browser. This works very well for the most part, except when the client is behind a "web accelerator" proxy which very aggressively caches the output from a web server, even if the `cache-control` header is `no-cache`. I need to send a very large amount of data, before the proxy decides to give me anything, meaning that the updates are delayed by a very long time.

I believe that this proxy doesn't conform to the HTTP standard, but I can't change the fact that they exist out there. Thus, I need a way to work around the issue.

Is there some trick (some magic header perhaps?) that I can use to ensure that my events are delivered in time?

Answer (score 3):

You have more options than just `no-cache` in the <kbd>Cache-Control</kbd> header with regards to caching instructions for both visitors browser, as well as any intermediate caching proxy servers:

- `private` or `public` ; a private response is specific to a user and shouldn't be cached, a public response may be cached.
- `no-cache` does mostly what it sounds like and is an instruction to re-validate the resource for each subsequent request. Although after validation proved the resource is still valid a cached response could still be served.
- `no-store` a clear instruction that the response must be treated as confidential and not stored at all, a bit stronger than the no-cache option above.
- `max-age` in seconds  overrides the Expires header and instructs when an asset is expired and should be purged from the cache.
- `s-maxage` in seconds the same as above, but for shared caches like content delivery networks.

You can try if combining them gives better results.

The simple alternative may of-course be to enable TLS where the web-accelerator simply can't read the data between your visitors and webserver anymore.